# Linux, Write output to the file and terminate it using Python

Tags: python, linux

There are various topics available on this very topic, "How to write output to the text file".
But my issue is different because the output to the command in question is continous.

What I want to do is, write the Output of the command `cgps -s` to the file `aaa.txt`

here is the code,

```
import signal
import os
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["cgps", "-s", ">> aaa.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

The code doesn't work at all and no file is created with the name `aaa.txt`

When I execute this command through terminal,

```
cgps -s > aaa.txt
```

Then I have to press CTRL+C to terminate the output from being written on the output file because the output is continuous.

Is there any way to just capture one output and write it to the file and terminate it using Python or using Command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to create a pipe. Try this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["cgps", "-s"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

with open("aaa.txt", "w") as f:
    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        if some_condition(): # <-- check whether you have enough output
            p.terminate()
            break
        f.writeline(line)

p.wait()
```